# Filter out words based on starting letters

Tags: unix, grep

I have a file where I dump my Firewall logs. Now I want to eliminate everything except the IP addresses from this file so that I can pipe them through uniq -c to allow for a quick overview. Cut doesnt work for this purpose due to varying entry lengths. So it seems like a grep problem, but I can't figure out the right syntax.
The entries that I want to filter for look like this:
SRC=Some-ipv6-address

The try that looked the best was

`grep -w '^SRC'=[1-9:]*`

But that only produced empty results.

A sample input:

```
[UFW BLOCK] IN=wp01 OUT= MAC=25:c5:a3:21:c1:7b:32:21:a9:3f:de:5e:21:aa 
SRC=2b32:14f9:c210:27486:0100:0000:0000:0001 
DST=1833:00b5:6f4b:7836:0f08:8ae5:87b3:4d04 LEN=60 
TC=0 HOPLIMIT=52 FLOWLBL=10001 PROTO=TCP 
SPT=80 DPT=56020 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
```

And the desired output:

```
2b32:14f9:c210:27486:0100:0000:0000:0001
```

But you probably would have to include SRC= to distinguish between destination and source and then cut the SRC part of with cut.

Anybody knows the right syntax for this?

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Try `grep -oP 'SRC=\K[0-9a-zA-Z:]+' file` if you have a GNU grep

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `sed` with a capture group, and use that group in the replacement.

```
sed -nE 's/^SRC=([a-fA-F0-9:]+)/\1/p' file
```

Output

```
2b32:14f9:c210:27486:0100:0000:0000:0001
```

The pattern matches

- `^` Start of string
- `SRC=` Match literally
- `([a-fA-F0-9:]+)` capture **group 1** match 1+ times any of the chars in the character class

In the sed command:

- `-n` does not print every line by default
- `/p` prints the replaced text
- `\1` refers to the captured value in group 1

Answer (score 0):

Using any sed or awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ sed -n 's/^SRC=//p' file
2b32:14f9:c210:27486:0100:0000:0000:0001

$ awk 'sub(/^SRC=/,"")' file
2b32:14f9:c210:27486:0100:0000:0000:0001
```